# Passing an array of strings to Range().Formula in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

As everyone knows filling cells with values one by one in VBA is much less efficient than bulk-filling them with an array of values. For the same optimisation reasons I would like to do that with an array of formulas. A very simple example would be something like:

```
Sub Fill_Using_Arrays()
  Dim i As Long
  Dim formulae(1 To 10000) As String

  For i = 1 To 10000
    formulae(i) = "=$A$" & i
  Next i

  [A2].Resize(10000).Formula = formulae
End Sub
```

However, If I do that it will fill the 10k cells with "=$A$1" and so on without actually evaluating the expressions. I tried running a `.Calculate` on the range as well, but that did nothing. Is it possible to achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While writing this question I found the solution:

The issue was the string array. I generally stay away from `Variant` due to the slight overhead. As someone coming from C++ declaring everything as variant feels very dirty, but anyway, in this case it is apparently necessary as passing a `String` will make it paste the value as a literal string.

This is somewhat counter-intuitive to me as passing a single string (not an array) to the `.Formula` property works. If anyone knows why I would be grateful for that information.

Anyway, working code would be:

```
Sub Fill_Using_Arrays()
  Dim i As Long
  Dim formulae(1 To 10000) As Variant ' Only change here

  For i = 1 To 10000
    formulae(i) = "=$A$" & i
  Next i

  [A2].Resize(10000).Formula = formulae
End Sub
```

Edit: To be clear, as a follow up I am curious why this works:

```
  [A2].Formula = formulae(1)
```

And fills this as an actual formula, not as a string.

Comment: Seems like overkill, unless you wanted absolute references in each row. `Range("A2:A10000").Formula = "=A1"`

Comment: @BigBen Interesting, I didn't know it would handle relative references like that. Anyway, for my use case I have some very complicated formulas I need to fill out for a large number of cells and sheets and therefore plan to abstract out the range in the end and save the actual saving for last to minimise run time.

Comment: @Comintern Well, I guess, however I also assumed that .Formula and .Value had slightly different logic as a .Formula naturally is a string, at least on some level. For `.Value` I totally agree, but what would you say a formula is if not a string?

Edit: Also, as I noted in my answer, VBA will gladly accept a String variable as a formula as long as you only set the formula for a single cell. E.g. `[A2].Formula = formulae(1)` in the example code of the question works "as expected".

Comment: Instead of using fixed number in loop and in last line, you can use `UBound(formulae)`

Comment: It has to handle this: `Sheet1.[A1].Formula = "Foo"`.  Note that it adds the explicit `'` string "tick" to the start of it. It is definitely type aware - `Sheet1.[A1].Formula = 42` is treated as a number. I'm guessing it performs the type check *first* (because, well, it kind of has to), and then just passes it to `Value` internally if it didn't get a `Variant()`.

Comment: For i = LBound(formulae) to UBound(formulae) is always preferable.